# PHP Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0

Tags: php, string, offset, initialization

I'm getting this error in my OpenCart log.
Says the error is on line 1 which is:

```
<?php if(isset($social_discount['name']) && $social_discount['name']!="") { ?>
```

Would highly appreciate any help to fix this.

Comment: and `this error` is ?

Comment: @hexblot `PHP Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0` :p

Comment: code added, forgot to put in the pre tags

Comment: are you sure `$social_discount` is an array?

Comment: im still quite new to php so im not sure, it should be

Answer (score 6):

To prevent this error, you should change your code like the following:

```
<?php if(is_array($social_discount) && isset($social_discount['name']) && $social_discount['name']!="") { ?>
```

Comment: leave in the isset() too, just in case of undefined index 'name'

Comment: You're right, edited.

Comment: that seemed to work! thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`$socialdiscount` is a string, not an array, so `$social_discount['name']` is treated as `$social_discount[0]` => first character of the string. `0` is not set means `$socialdiscount` is an *empty* string.

Comment: so how should that line of code actually be?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with _that_ line of code. However, I suspect there is something seriously wrong with the lines _before_ that line, which make your `$socialdiscount` variable an empty string `""` rather then the expected array.